# Is it possible to do blue green deployments with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Looking to make updates to a google function without potential loss in service or down time. Does GCP support a blue-green deployment for functions or only for applications? if not blue-green, are there other solutions with google functions to avoid these issues?

Comment: Is this question related to [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now (Jan 2019), there's no option to perform Cloud Functions deployments as you described. Only the last version for a Cloud Function is available and reachable and you can't switch traffic between versions, as you'd do with App Engine. Note that there's already a [Public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119335117) open that includes this.